# Split custom list based on values in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two custom lists. One list is called `detailList` and the other `hldList`. Below is a simplified version.

```
class Details
{
    string Fund
    string DT
}

class Holding
{
    string Fund
    string Name
    double Price
    double Amount
}
```

What I want to do is split the `hldList`. All Funds in `hldList` exist in the `detailList`. I would like to split the `hldList` based on the `DT` value in the `detailList`, a simple example below,

```
 detailList
 Fund       DT
 LMON       E
 LMPN       K
 PLLM       E
```

I will only populate the `Fund` property in the `hldList` for this example but the other properties would be populated.

```
 hldList
 Fund
 LMON
 LMON
 LMON
 LMPN
 LMPN
 PLLM
 PLLM
```

So I would like this to be split on the `DT` property of the `detailList` so the answer should be,

```
 E List          K List
 LMON            LMPN
 LMON            LMPN
 LMON
 PLLM
 PLLM
```

I take it the best way to achieve this is to use LINQ? However am unsure how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`  to group by this property. You just need to link both lists with `Join`:

```
var dtGroups = from h in hldList
               join d in detailList 
               on h.Fund equals d.Fund
               group h by d.DT into dtGroup 
               select dtGroup;

foreach (var grp in dtGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Funds:{1}"
        , grp.Key, string.Join(",", grp.Select(h => h.Fund)));
```

If you want a `List<Holding>` for each dt-group:

```
IEnumerable<List<Holding>> dtHoldingLists = 
               from h in hldList
               join d in detailList 
               on h.Fund equals d.Fund
               group h by d.DT into dtGroup 
               select dtGroup.ToList();
```

Comment: The code above works. I'm basically splitting my list into two groups. Each list is then passed to a method which is expecting the parameter to be of type List<Holding>. How can I select the list based on its key value?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Say d.DT takes two values "A" & "B" is there anyway to tell which list belongs to A or B. So if the Funds in the hldList are A's they need to be sent to method A & if the Funds are B they need to be sent to method B. So need to know which list is which, does that make sense?

Comment: ignore my previous comment. I used the first code section you posted. The just did if(grp.Key="A") List<Holding> myHld = grp.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

First of all join both the lists as

```
var result = (from b in hldList
              join a in detailList on b.Fund equals a.Fund
              select new { a.DT, a.Fund, b.(*Other Columns)}).OrderBy(a=>a.DT).ToList();
```

then do grouping

```
var nList = result.GroupBy(a => a.DT).ToList();
```

And finally you can loop through each item of the splitted list

```
foreach (var it in nList)
{
    //Here you can process each list one by one 
    nList.Where(i => i.Key == it.Key).ToList();
}
```